# Read local JSON file and return determinate keys for each object within it, into an array

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to access a local JSON file which stores nodeIDs as objects and longitude,latitude, adjacent nodeIDs as their values.

Example: `[{"33583379": {"lat": 40.7046387, "lon": -74.0167729, "adj": ["33583379", "1659428533"]}, "33583380": {"lat": 40.7043271, "lon": -74.0169624, "adj": ["33583379", "33583381"]}, etc.}]`

I'm trying to return just the `Object name`, `"lat"` and `"long"` values of each object and save them into arrays like this:
  `[33583379, -73.984293,40.729468],
  [33583380, -73.987752,40.732017]`

I have tried using `Object.keys(data[0])` but returns all the object names and I can't find a way to retrieve it one by one in the same for loop.

Any help is appreciated. Spent hours trying to figure it out but I was only able to access the JSON but not the actual key values I need and formatting them into an array. PS: My project is in React.

Comment: Access a local JSON file? In the *browser*? Not likely... what are you actually trying to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a json file by using `require('location-of-json')` . You can extract the lat,long details in a for..in loop and push the values into an array .

```
a=require('./test.json')
data=[]

for(var i in this.a[0]){
  console.log(new Array(this.a[0][i].lat,this.a[0][i].lon))
  this.data.push(new Array(this.a[0][i].lat,this.a[0][i].lon))
}
```

I have implemented the above in react . Please check : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nphzxn